# MONGO::Error::MaxBSONSize : The document exceeds maximum allows BSONB object after serialization

Tags: json, ruby, mongodb, mongodb-query

when i run my ruby script which insert a multiple Json array inside a multiple documents, occur an issue:  "MONGO::Error::MaxBSONSize : The document exceeds maximum allows BSONB object after serialization".
How can i solve this problem please?
i had no idea.
i want to maintain same structure: 1 doc for 1 json array.
I saw that is a tool call GridFs, but i have no idea how to use it in ruby script

Comment: Why not store the elements from your (json) array in a separate collection and use _id references between the documents? (as described in [Normalized Data Models](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/data-model-design/#normalized-data-models))

Comment: because performance drops, for example 1 json array is composed by 1750 single json,  and i would create 1750 collections, and this for another 100 000  000 json array

Comment: so hard to handle

Comment: You would need 2 collections: one to hold your (formerly embedded) entries from the arrays and one to hold the originals docs.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo allows 16MB document at most, see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#document-size-limit). The only built-in way to workaround it is [gridfs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/ruby-driver/master/reference/gridfs/) where each document is split into chunks and mongo driver manages working with them

Comment: but gridfs split only documents that axceed 16MB, or split all document?

Comment: if gridfs split all document, i would work on a billions of document and the performance would be very slow

Comment: exist one method, that using gridfs, would improve performance?

Comment: gridfs works with binary data in chunk collection and metadata you need to choose in a file collection. Read here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/gridfs/.

Comment: but the document that exceed 16MB is in a collection of thousands document

Comment: I can insert a condition in the ruby script according to which the document that exceeds the size is divided into parts

Comment: I doubt you can use any custom conditions/logic here, you have option: either use gridfs or apply a custom logic to cut documents to 16 MB when it's needed with your custom logic

Comment: i tried to see better and when i run the script gives me this error: ""MONGO::Error::MaxBSONSize : "The document exceeds maximum allows BSONB object after serialization", even though the file weighs less than 16mb. (720kb), how it possible§?

Comment: Just to clarify you took a single document (720kb) in a single insertOne operation?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you currently have a structure roughly similar to this:

```js
{ _id: 1001, name: "first", data: [{ name: "foo" }, { name: "bar" }] }
{ _id: 1002, name: "second", data: [{ name: "baz" }, { name: "qux" }] }
```

i.e. documents with some fields and an embedded array that can hold *many* items. Although MongoDB has great support for embedded data, there's a [limit](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents) to the size a single document can have (~16 MB).

If you want to handle an arbitrary amount of data while still being able to query that data, you should consider separating it into two collections and modelling a [one-to-many relationship](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents).

One collections holds the original documents *without* the embedded data:

```js
{ _id: 1001, name: "first" }
{ _id: 1002, name: "second" }
```

The other collection holds the formerly embedded data. In this collection, each document *references* the original document using its `_id`:

```js
{ _id: 2001, name: "foo", parent_id: 1001 }
{ _id: 2002, name: "bar", parent_id: 1001 }
{ _id: 2003, name: "baz", parent_id: 1002 }
{ _id: 2004, name: "qux", parent_id: 1002 }
```

With this approach, you don't have to manage growing arrays and you can store as many documents as you like.